# how to include the codeigniter websocket library correctly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpwebsocket

I found this library to use web-socket protocol in code-igniter

[codeigniter-websocket](https://packagist.org/packages/takielias/codeigniter-websocket)
and I did all the steps.
I even make the same example in the description 
and I got this Error

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested class: Codeigniter_websocket
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug of that package. It does not load the package library due to incorrect vendor path. This bug has been fixed.
[Codeigniter WebSocket](https://github.com/takielias/codeigniter-websocket) Library has been updated. Please Update the library. If you face installation problem You may also check the [Codeigniter WebSocket Example](https://github.com/takielias/codeigniter-websocket-example)